# How to fix the dropdown list in bootstrap

Tags: toggle, dropdown

is it possible to fix the dropdown list items after first click? I'm using bootstrap and have created a header with two Menu items. I want, if user clicks on first menu item then it will be open until unless when he/she clicks on second menu item.

this is something, I've already prepared. The below code will produce fixed header at top position of the web page with two Menu items called Menu1 and Menu2

Menu1 has 5 submenu items which will be displayed in horizontal list.

```
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/logo.png" style="padding-top:6px" class="pull-left" />

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">Menu1</a>
                        </li>

<li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">Menu2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel navbar-inverse" id="submenu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="one">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu1", "Submenu1", "Submenu1Controller")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu2", "Submenu2", "Submenu2Controller")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu3", "Submenu3", "Submenu3Controller")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu4", "Submenu4", "Submenu4Controller")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu5", "Index", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>


        <div class="container-fluid body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My Website</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>

    slight adjustments to the .panel css in bootstrap.css file to make

    .panel {
      margin-bottom: 0px; 
      background-color: #fff;
      border: .5px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
              box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    }
```

now what I want is, when user clicks on menu1 then it will display the associated submenu items and list will keep open (not collapsed) unit unless user click on Menuitem2.

This means that in second or next attempt if he/she click on Menu1 again or click any of the associated SubMenu item under menu1 then list will keep open and not get collapsed.

Comment: if you have getting tired please put your code

Comment: @core114 - I've edited my question with the code I'm trying. Not sure why someone voted it negative.

Comment: guys please do not mark it negative. this is something very tricky which I want to develope for my user.